# Threadsafe way to access database using django

Tags: database, django, thread-safety, sharing

As far as i know and hell, experienced it isn't possible to share `django` db connection for threads.

I have searched around and found two solutions for this problem:

1. Using direct `SQL` connection by using relevant DBMS driver directly.
2. Use `sqlalchmeny` and its session poll thing.

Isn't there really any other way? isn't it possible to ask `django` to create new connection for thread (sounds something simple and useful to me!)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread-safety issue with the DB has nothing to do with the connection; it's when two threads try to alter the same piece of data simulataneously, or even one trying to write while the other tries to read. In order to prevent this, you simply need to lock the table when one of your threads needs to do something with it. A quick and easy way with Django 1.4+ is to use [`select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update), which will lock the table until you do an `update` operation.

Comment: Thanks, what will happen when some other threads tries to write to locked table? is there a queue?